PCF8575 weird behaviour
So I designed a PCB in which I used PCF8575 i/o expander in combination with 74HC14 logic inverter and ULN2003A transistors, and my idea was the following:
Pull the PCF8575's outputs high and send low signal to 74HC14 which will send a 3.3V signal to ULN2003A because I have read that PCF8575 cant provide strong high signal and also the i/o pins are HIGH at startup.
But unfortunately I'm getting an unexpected result. The relays are not switching and after a few seconds they start to switch rapidly on their own. I soldered a second PCB just to be sure, and the same problem is happening. I also noticed that the WIFI led is shining a bit more that the other on both boards but I don't know if it is somehow related. I have double checked the schematic and the layout but I can't find the problem.



OK. So what have you done to debug the issue? Measured voltages on ULN input, HC14 input, I2C bus, anywhere? Do you have an oscilloscope? Logic analyzer? Also there is no question, what is it that you are asking?

Did you simulate your schematic in proteus or a similar software?

@Justme I measured 12V on ULN input, 3.3V on 74HC14 and PCF8575 input. I do not have an oscilloscope, only a multimeter. I'm asking for advice if there is some mistake in my pcb design or what is causing my issue.

@liaifat85 I did not, I haven't heard of this software. Will give it a try.

@k0cka I have to ask where those measurements are taken from? Having 12V on ULN input is impossible unless it is damaged. Do you mean the supplies? I meant inputs, not supplies. Supplies are important too, but then talk about supplies, not input.

Is GND at J2 and J3 connected? I cannot see a blue track at those pins.

@Justme sorry for misunderstanding. I measured the PCF's output pins after startup and some of the pins have 1.8V, 2.5, 2.9, 3.15 and some 3.3V. So I feel like the problem starts there. But now I noticed in the logs(im using esphome) that there is an error saying  "Recovery: failed, SDA is held low on the bus" and also  "Communication with PCF8574 failed!". I added a BME280 sensor and the logs says "Communication with BME280 failed!". So it looks like I have a problem in my I2C line I guess, but I don't know what is the exact problem.

@Jens yes they are connected to GND.

@k0cka If the PCF fails to work properly, have you made sure it has power, is it properly soldered, no PCB tracks cut, is it mounted in correct orientation etc? The problem is weird, no communication and strange voltages. Also you talk about PCF8575 but program talks about PCF8574, they are completely different and incompatible chips. Make sure what you really have and what the software tries to control.

@Justme I made sure it has power, good connections and also in good orientation. I also tried to swap it for another one but the problem is still the same and it is happening on 2 different PCB's. And yes the program talks about PCF8574 but there is a option to use PCF8575 by setting pcf8575: true - https://esphome.io/components/pcf8574. I know it's weird, that's why I created this topic. I made a version with MCP23017 and without the 74HC14 and it's working great, so I don't understand what is the problem on this PCB.

The 12 V supply VDD has no decoupling capacitor on board. It is worth a try, just to be sure.
